# How to centre underaccent under letter?

Tags: math-mode, accents

Here's the M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{\ensuremath{\underaccent{\mathclap{#2}}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\ensuremath{\undernum{\vec{#2}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mvec{a}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

One can see that n is not centred underneath the letter. So, mathclap isn't right here -- how should I centre n?

Comment: It seems like a better definition would be `\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\underset{#1}{\mathbf{#2}}}`.

Comment: @Werner Not so sure anymore that that would be the better definition, because it has its own problems. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227893/how-to-fix-uneven-sizing-of-glyphs-that-are-underset-below-some-other-text-using

Comment: For a consistent underscript, you can insert a strut (as already suggested). If the line-spacing is an issue, then you should consider an alternative notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing bit is the fact that a subscript comes with some additional space in the amount of `\scriptspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{\mathpalette\under@num{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\under@num}[2]{\under@@num{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\under@@num}[3]{%
  \oalign{$\m@th#1#2$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1{}_{#3}\kern-\scriptspace$\hidewidth}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\undernum{\vec{#2}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mvec{a}+\mvec[\mathrm{x}]{x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might use your code, suitably modified (and with the bad `\ensuremath` taken off), but it's just much less efficient.

```
\usepackage{mathtools,accents}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{\underaccent{\mathclap{#2}\kern-scriptspace}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\undernum{\vec{#2}}{#1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing the shift is due to an italic correction that might otherwise be expected in math mode.  But in this case, the overletter is not italic.  Thus, a simple stack will center the underscript.

This first MWE shows the before and after:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{\ensuremath{\underaccent{\mathclap{#2}}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\ensuremath{\undernum{\vec{#2}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mvec{a}
\quad    
   \stackunder[1pt]{\mathbf{a}}{\scriptscriptstyle n}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A macro implementation of the revised formulation would be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackunder[1pt]{\vec{#2}}{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \mvec{a}
\quad    
   \mvec[xx]{\vec{Z}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a suitable amount of math kerning -- `2.5mu` seems about right -- in order to center the "accent" below the associated letter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,accents}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{%
     \underaccent{\mkern2.5mu\mathclap{#2}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\undernum{\vec{#2}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\mvec{a}$ $\mvec[xx]{Z}$
\end{document}
```