# How to fix uneven sizing of glyphs that are underset below some other text using \underset?

Tags: amsmath

Here's a M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{\ensuremath{\underaccent{\mathclap{#2}}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\underset{#1}{\mathbf{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Multivector notation.]
    $\mvec[0]{x} \in \mathbb{R}$, or $\mvec[0]{x}$ is a scalar, or a $0$-vector. We simply write $x$ instead of $\mvec[0]{x}$ (notice no bold). $\mvec[1]{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, or $\mvec[1]{y}$ is a traditional vector, or a $1$-vector. We simply write $\vec{y}$ instead of $\mvec[1]{y}$. $\mvec[n]{z} \in \mathbb{G}^n$, or $\mvec[n]{z}$ is multivector, or more specifically, an $n$-vector. 
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the uneven size of underset letters (n) versus underset numerals. How can I fix this issue? Setting \scriptscriptstyle like so: `\underset{\scriptscriptstyle#1}`, does not fix the difference in proportions, as it simply makes everything smaller.

Comment: The size is not uneven, it's the default. You can try inserting `\strut` inside `\mathbf` in your definition to have numbers and letters on the same baseline, but the result is not so good. Your definition disrupts the baseline skip.

Comment: @karlkoeller Your comment seems to be the correct answer, would you care making it one, please? :)

Comment: @yo' Done, just for removing this question from the unaswered list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve what you want you can add a `\mathstrut` in the definition of `\mvec`:

```
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\underset{\scriptscriptstyle#1}{\mathbf{\mathstrut#2}}}
```

Note, however, that the baseline skip is disrupted by this definition.

To have homogeneous baseline skips, if you really want to use such a definition, I suggest you to increase the baseline skip globally, e.g. with

```
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\undernum}[2]{\ensuremath{\underaccent{\mathclap{#2}}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{\underset{\scriptscriptstyle#1}{\mathbf{\mathstrut#2}}}

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont

\begin{definition}[Multivector notation.]
    $\mvec[0]{x} \in \mathbb{R}$, or $\mvec[0]{x}$ is a scalar, or a $0$-vector. 
    We simply write $x$ instead of $\mvec[0]{x}$ (notice no bold). $\mvec[1]{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, 
    or $\mvec[1]{y}$ is a traditional vector, or a $1$-vector. We simply write $\vec{y}$ instead of 
    $\mvec[1]{y}$. $\mvec[n]{z} \in \mathbb{G}^n$, or $\mvec[n]{z}$ is multivector, or more 
    specifically, an $n$-vector.

    \lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Comment: The answer is "correct" in the sense that it gives the OP exactly what he/she was asking for. The result, though, illustrates vividly why it's in general much better to adapt one's notation -- say, using `u`, `v`, and `w` instead of `x`, `y`, and `z` to denote the three vector types. That way, there's never a need to override some of the defaults of TeX's symbol placement algorithms...

Comment: Of course, the usefulness of `\ensuremath` in the macros is disputable. But, above all, `\mathstrut` is *not* the tool to use, because it sets the subscripts too far away from the symbol they refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\underset` will lead to uneven line spacing. I suggest to not use it and rather go to a lower level alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2][n]{%
  \oalign{%
    \smash[b]{$\vec{#2}$}\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vskip\lineskip}
    \hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle\vphantom{1}#1$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}



\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Multivector notation.]
$\mvec[0]{x} \in \mathbb{R}$, or $\mvec[0]{x}$ is a scalar, or a $0$-vector. We simply 
write $x$ instead of $\mvec[0]{x}$ (notice no bold). $\mvec[\,1]{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, or 
$\mvec[\,1]{y}$ is a traditional vector, or a $1$-vector. We simply write $\vec{y}$ instead 
of $\mvec[\,1]{y}$. $\mvec[n]{z} \in \mathbb{G}^n$, or $\mvec[n]{z}$ is multivector, or more 
specifically, an $n$-vector.
\end{definition}

However, $\mvec[1]{g}$ is hopeless, while $\mvec[\,n]{y}$ is tolerable.

\end{document}
```

I only left the code and packages necessary for the example. Note that you should use `\vec` in the definition of `\mvec`. Using `\scriptscriptstyle` and small separation (with `\vphantom{1}`) makes the interline spacing less uneven than what you'd obtain with `\underset`. In the case of **y**, manual correction is necessary in order to avoid the letters bump into each other, but the example also shows that letters such as **g** must not be used.

[image]

I'd never use such a notation myself.

Comment: I agree that with your solution the subscript is closer to the symbol, but, if it's possible, this looks even worst than using `\mathstrut`, in my opinion.

Comment: The right solution would be not to use at all such a notation.

Comment: @karlkoeller That was indeed the sense of my final comment. `;-)`

Comment: @karlkoeller I am not sure why the right solution would be to not use such notation at all. It seems that by doing so, I am using the limitation of my tools to define my notation, which should not be the case?

Comment: @user89 I'm just saying that there is probably a different notation for multivectors, better from a typographical point of view.